# python3.9 pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)")

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

pls tell me how to deal with the problem

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',port=3306,user ='root',password ='123456',database ='account',charset ='utf8')                  
cursor = conn.cursor()                            
cursor.execute('show databases;')                             
for x in cursor:  
    print (x)
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

[run result]
File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 353, in **init**
self.connect()
File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 664, in connect
raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)")

mysql version is mysql-8.0.28-macos11-x86_64

localhost change to 127.0.0.1 , is also not ok～～
but the same params is ok in navicat expect for
the config 'use socket file : /tmp/mysql.sock'~~
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POYMM.png)
in navicat , if i do not check the socket option ,i receive the same problem as python code above

expect to link mysql succesfully , thx